# Cant get an accessToken from FB sdk

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, instagram, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to get images from my Instagram account to my web page. So I try to use FB php sdk and get accessToken first according this [documentation](https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk). But it returns null. I don't know what is wrong with the code.

```
public function getMedia()
{
    $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => self::APP_ID,
        'app_secret' => self::APP_SECRET,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
        //'default_access_token' => '{access-token}', // optional
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();  // Whichever helper I use access-token is null

    dd($helper->getAccessToken());
}
```

I need help with it. It could be so simple.

EDIT:

After few hours I have this, but the last command throws an Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException Invalid OAuth access token signature. As I see the token is app id and app secret joined with pipe. "733163597544229|xxxxxxxxxxxxx9d14362xxxx3a6". This should work but does not work.

```
public function getMedia()
{
    $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => self::APP_ID_FB,
        'app_secret' => self::APP_SECRET_FB,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
        //'default_access_token' => '{access-token}', // optional
    ]);

    $token = $fb->getApp()->getAccessToken();
    $response = $fb->get('https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=media_url,media_type', $token->getValue());

}
```

Comment: perhaps you could debug `$helper` with xdebug, or var_dump it to see if there's an error message in that object somewhere with some info about what went wrong?

Comment: Try `$response = $helper->getLastResponse(); var_dump($response);`, what does that output?

Comment: Hi, it was night in EU. So if I try to dump 
  `dd($helper->getError(), $helper->getErrorDescription(), $helper->getErrorReason(), $helper);` there are three null values and the last one is object without any error.

Comment: I have an edit. But without success.

Comment: Can you try switching your `default_graph_version` to [`v8.0`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version8.0) to see if that helps in any way? It might not matter, but `2.10` is pretty old

Comment: It is the same. Invalid OAuth access token signature

Comment: _“As I see the token is app id and app secret joined with pipe.”_ - that means you only got an _app_ access token, which is not the right kind of token to request data from a specific account to begin with. You need to send the user through the login flow first, by redirecting them to the login dialog URL. https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk/blob/master/docs/examples/facebook_login.md#loginphp

Comment: No I dont want to login user. There is a html panel with IG photos on homepage of the web. Photos comes from account which owner is the same as owner of the web. I dont want to log in anybody else. It is content from the owner account. I have all required credentials.

Comment: You still need to implement the process of getting the correct permissions from that specific user.

Comment: Ok but where is documentation to it? I need to make it on background server to server. No client window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood the docs correctly, if you want to get an access token dynamically, according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web, you need enable fb-login for your app

1. https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
2. select your app
3. add fb-login & follow the tips.

Otherwise you should just be able to get an access token for your app from the web interface and use that over and over.

See also : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens

There's also:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v9.0

Which enables you to generate an access token, and test out a call to the graph api, AND allows you to export code you can copy/paste:

[image]

```php
try {
  // Returns a `FacebookFacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    '/me',
    '{access-token}'
  );
} catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

EDIT:

I see in your original question you state:

> As I see the token is app id and app secret joined with pipe. "733163597544229|xxxxxxxxxxxxx9d14362xxxx3a6". This should work but does not work.

According to the docs, if you want to supply an access token as `{app_id}|{client-token}` (not sure what secret you're using here) you should append this to the URL, which is not in the URL you're using.

See example here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#clienttokens

The URL they use is:

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/{your-user-id}/accounts?access_token={user-access-token}
```

So for you this be:

```
$response = $fb->get('https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=media_url,media_type&access_token=733163597544229|{client_token}');
```

EDIT 2:

I managed to get your sample working so perhaps these screen shots will help:

### PHP Code:

```php
<?php
$accessToken="EAAJIZAj**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ZD";

require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php'; // change path as needed

//echo __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '642**********502',
    'app_secret' => '0185*****************f743',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
    'default_access_token' => "{$accessToken}"
]);

try {
    // Get the \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
    // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
    $response = $fb->get('/me');
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$me = $response->getGraphUser();
echo 'Logged in as ' . $me->getName();

?>
```

I took the source code from https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk and copied the `src/Facebook` dir into my project. I amended the path location in my code

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php'; // change path as needed

//echo __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php'; //<< comment out everything else and check the path is correct with this.
```

Working code: (same as above) with successful output shown at the bottom of the screen shot.

[image]

If you need to get the app secret go to the apps settings to uncover it:

[image]

Seems you were right - the access token does have an expiry and I had to refresh mine since using it yesterday.

Comment: So if somebody do not log in to my app, he will not see any content from instagram. Am I right? This is not what I want. May be I still dont understand.

Comment: If you want to have users log in to your app in order to see content from instagram you need to add the facebook-login module to your app. If you just want to show content without requiring login, just use a pre-generated access token for your app and anyone will be able to use it

Comment: But that token is only for 60 days isnt it?

Comment: The docs don't mention a time-limit/expiry so you should be fine

Comment: I see you're talking about the long-lived user access tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing I don't think this is what you're going to be using if you use an application access token.

Comment: without luck. me/ endpoint requires user access token.

Comment: Check the edit - I'm not certain what `secret` you're using but it looks like you should be using, specifically, a client-token which may not be the same thing

Comment: `$response = $fb->get('https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,medai_type&access_token='.self::APP_ID_FB.'|'.self::APP_CLIENT_TOKEN_FB);` Throws an error,- Tried accessing nonexisting field (media_type) on node type (URL) I dont understand. Where is the collection of medias?

Comment: there's a typo in that URL? `medai`

Comment: It is only a typo in comment.

Comment: Check "Edit 2:" - working sample + explanation of what I did to get it working. You should get a warning if the access-token has expired

Comment: Also tested with: `$response = $fb->get('/me', $app_id . "|" . $app_secret );` - it fails with `Graph returned an error: Error validating application. Invalid application ID.`

Comment: Have no time for now. I am lost in it. Your example is for FB user but I need IG content, dont know if it will work. Hope so.

Comment: Did you follow this? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started It should be the same process - set up account, get IG token/secret, make requests

Comment: You also look to need to complete an App review to get access, since the legacy API was switched off June 29 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-review

Comment: Also unless you're a business they won't approve you right now due to COVID 19 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/individual-verification - I think this answers the question until further notice.

Comment: It can be the reason. That verification requires video. I try to make it at weekend.

Comment: Yes you spend a lot of time with me. Thanks a lot. But still no success.

Comment: It impossible without the relevant access token. Instagram aren't providing api access tokens right now. I think this answers the question for now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this will probably not work to get the access token .
To get access token you need to implement the  login with facebook in your app to get the access token . If your app is only used by limited user then you can get access token on this link  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/  but if your app is used by wide range of user and each user has their own data then you need to implement oauth2 in your app